# Install cronjob from file to a specific user

Tags: cron, crontab, cronjob

I have an install script that sets up a user.

Using the install script, I want to apply a cronjob that gets executed by that user (myuser):

```
0 4 * * * /home/myuser/script-to-run-at-4am.sh
```

I have found that using the following command I can edit the crontab from another user:

```
sudo crontab -u myuser -e
```

Is there an alternative command I can use that would apply my cron job from a file to the myuser crontab?

Answer (score 0):

crontab files are stored in */var/spool/cron/crontabs/*
so you could create that file directly within your script with something like:

```
echo "0 4 * * * /home/myuser/script-to-run-at-4am.sh" > /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to install the crontab for the particular user is (as per man)

```
crontab -u <username> <file_contaning_cronjobs>
```